# trigonometric function inside newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to know if there is a way to define a variable that depends on a trigonometric function, like this.

```
 \newcommand{\cosTheta}{cos(30)}
```

Such that it is parsed before using it in a tikz segment, like this

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.5]
      \draw (0,0) -- (\cosTheta,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Right now, I'm getting the error

```
 Package pgf Error: No shape named -1*cos(30 is known.
```

Sorry if the tags were not chosen well, please feel free to add to them. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's a problem with the parentheses: `({\cosTheta},0)` might work.

Comment: Does that force parcing at compile time? What if I wanted to define another newcommand based on \cosTheta?

Comment: Please, supplement your question with an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Actually, this works just fine, thanks again!

Comment: @egreg Please drop an answer.  This will be 200th :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `\cosTheta` is expanded, TeX sees a `)` that matches the opening one, because only `{}` pairs are matched by counting them. So just do

```
\draw (0,0) -- ({\cosTheta},0);
```

and the problem should be solved.

Comment: This looks great, and I would like to accept it, but I can't help but notice that \draw (0,0) -- (1-{\cosTheta},0); doesn't work. Can you elaborate on this too? When I try this, the error I get is "Missing number, treated as zero"

Comment: @Charlie You have to brace the whole expression: `\draw(0,0)--({1-\cosTheta},0);`